# How to choose a candidate for parallelization in CUDA?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

[This book](https://books.google.pl/books?id=3LZpEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%22Example%201.3%20gpusum%20GPU%20calculation%20of%20a%20sin%20integral%22&source=bl&ots=-78WZbtHp0&sig=ACfU3U0Qf7AcCyf4ECCTDHawFM-A0A3FoQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu5tiB26P-AhXR6CoKHWTxDxMQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Example%201.3%20gpusum%20GPU%20calculation%20of%20a%20sin%20integral%22&f=false) says that, in the following program, the marked-for loop can be parallelized,  because, each iteration of the loop is independent and performs the same set of computations, which makes it a good fit for parallelization.

However, the for loop inside the function `sinsum()` cannot be parallelized because each term in the `sinsum()` function depends on the previous term. Therefore, it is not possible to break down the computation into independent units of work that can be executed concurrently.

I haven't understood the above argument.

If we look at the for loop inside the main function,

```
for(int step = 0; step < steps; step++)
{
    float x = step_size*step;
    cpu_sum += sinsum(x, terms); 
}
```

In the second statement, `sinsum()` is taking `x` as an argument. Therefore, it can be said that `sinsum()` is dependent on the value of `x`.

So, from a parallelism point of view, what is the difference between the loop inside `simsum()` and the loop where `simsum()` is called?

```
/*
    D:\>cpusum.exe 1000000 1000
    cpu sum = 1.9999999974,steps 1000000 terms 1000 time 1818.959 ms
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cxtimers.h"

inline float sinsum(float x, int terms)
{
    // sin(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! ...
    float term = x; // first term of series
    float sum = term; // sum of terms so far
    float x2 = x*x;
    for(int n = 1; n < terms; n++)
    {
        term *= -x2 / (float)(2*n*(2*n+1));
        sum += term;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int steps = (argc >1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 10000000;
    int terms = (argc >2) ? atoi(argv[2]) : 1000;
    double pi = 3.14159265358979323;
    double step_size = pi/(steps-1); // n-1 steps
    cx::timer tim;
    double cpu_sum = 0.0;
    
    ////////// candidate for parallelization /////////// 
    for(int step = 0; step < steps; step++)
    {
        float x = step_size*step;
        cpu_sum += sinsum(x, terms); // sum of Taylor series
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    double cpu_time = tim.lap_ms(); // elapsed time
    
    // Trapezoidal Rule correction
    cpu_sum -= 0.5 * (sinsum(0.0,terms) + sinsum(pi, terms));
    cpu_sum *= step_size;
    printf("cpu sum = %.10f,steps %d terms %d time %.3f ms\n", cpu_sum, steps, terms, cpu_time);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although a somewhat artificial example, `sinsum` has been implemented as a recurrence relation, whereas the main loop is a linear relation. Linear relations are amenable to parallelisation, recurrence relations are not.

Comment: `x` can easily be computed by each thread using its index. `term` depends on the previous iteration of itself which is non-trivial.

Comment: That being said, one could also parallelize `sinsum` using a scan, I guess. It's just a bit more complicated. If there were much more `terms` than `steps`, it might make sense to choose differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to visualize the difference is to mentally/physically unroll the loops and look at the form of the terms they emit.

The `sinsum` loop:

```
float term = x; // first term of series
float sum = term; // sum of terms so far
float x2 = x*x;
for(int n = 1; n < terms; n++)
{
    term *= -x2 / (float)(2*n*(2*n+1));
    sum += term;
}
```

for this:

```
term[0] = x
term[1] = term[0] * -x^2 / 6    // -x^3/3!
term[2] = term[1] * -x^2 / 20   //  x^5/5! 
term[3] = term[2] * -x^2 / 42   // -x^7/7!
.....
```

It should be obvious that each term relies on the results of the previous term, and the terms must be calculated in order. That becomes non-trivial to calculate in parallel because of the recurrence relation between terms in the series expansion.

Whereas in the other loop:

```
for(int step = 0; step < steps; step++)
{
    float x = step_size*step;
    cpu_sum += sinsum(x, terms); // sum of Taylor series
}
```

for this:

```
cpu_sum[0] = sinsum(0, terms)
cpu_sum[1] = sinsum(step, terms)
cpu_sum[2] = sinsum(2*step, terms)
cpu_sum[3] = simsum(3*step, terms)
```

It should be obvious that each term is completely independent and could be calculated in any order without affecting the value of that term. This linear relation is trivial to parallelise using a standard parallel reduction.

In general, it is impossible to divorce the process of writing numerical code to perform a specific operation from the mathematical properties of that operation. As such you may find it more instructive to start the journey with a pencil and a piece of paper, understand how the math works, then try and write code, rather than writing code first and then trying to understand why it doesn't work because of mathematical flaws.