# How do CUDA threads know which piece of data they should work on?

Tags: cuda

As far as I understand, CUDA kernels are executed in parallel by many threads on the GPU.

Each thread executes the same kernel code. I.e., the kernel code is not copied.

Each thread operates on a different piece of data. I.e., before starting to work on data, the threads already know which data they should work on.

My question is, How do threads know which piece of data they should operate on?

Comment: There are special variables/registers `threadIdx` and `blockIdx` that allow the programmer to calculate an unique index for each thread that can then be used to access memory. I.e. there is no magic, the programmer needs to "tell" the threads what data to work on.

Comment: Yes, if you don't use these indices every thread or every block will really just do the same operation on the same data which would be a waste.

Comment: See [CUDA C++ Programming Guide - Programming Model - Thread Hierarchy](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, How do threads know which piece of data they should operate on?

They don't.

It is your job as the programmer to devise a [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76001497/681865) to divide whatever data-parallel task you have amongst the threads you [choose to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76767339/681865) to execute that task in parallel. As you [must](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75976116/681865) now be [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76878753/681865), the CUDA execution model provide a simple, logical numbering system for threads within a block, and blocks within a grid, from which you can construct a scheme to assist you in assigning unique parallel work tasks to individual threads or groups of threads.

NVIDIA also provide additional levels of abstraction to program groups of threads to operate [cooperatively](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cooperative-groups/), and various domain specific libraries which can implement [parallel algorithm primitives](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cub/index.html) and [linear algebra operations](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cutlass-linear-algebra-cuda/) at different levels of granularity within a running kernel.

Comment: @user366312: if you find that a comment is inappropriate, then best to flag it for moderation and then ignore it. Please don't make the situation worse by posting a comment that is even *more* inappropriate and here, verging on racism.

Comment: @user366312: then best of luck on your journeys